# What is the difference between a verb's 名詞修飾型 and 辞書形

Tags: grammar

One of my textbooks, for grammar pattern construction, sometimes indicates "[動-辞書形] +", and I also sometime "[動・い形・な形・名] の名詞修飾型 +".

For verbs I thought that both of these are the same. Is that correct?

If not what is the difference? Also in English is the second form what is called the nominal form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the attributive form (連体形/名詞修飾形) of a verb looks exactly the same as its dictionary-form (終止形/辞書形) in *modern Japanese*. But that was not true in archaic/classic Japanese. From Wikipedia:

> #### [Attributive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb#Japanese)
>
> ... modern Japanese verbs have the same form whether predicative or attributive. (The only exception is the copula, which is da or desu when used predicatively and na when used attributively.) Historically, however, these had been separate forms.

So for historical reasons it's worth distinguishing the two.

And 連体形 and 終止形 are still different in na-adjectives (i.e., 簡単**な**本 vs この本は簡単**だ**), so thinking them as different things is a good idea for the sake of consistency.

Comment: An example would be 死ぬ(dictionary form -"to die") and 死ぬる時(attributive form - "time of dying/death") in Classical Japanese, however they are both appear as the same form in modern Japanese 死ぬ (dictionary form) and 死ぬ時 (attributive form).